# How to find the modulus of a function in assembly code for IJVM

Tags: assembly, modulus

I am learning assembly code and am trying to write a function for assembly code that finds the modulus of two numbers.  The pseudocode for this problem would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try repeated subtraction.

```
modulus(a, b)
    while a >= b
        a -= b
    return a
```